# How can I get a 120 degree angle with crochet chains?

Tags: crocheting

I am trying to make the edge of a diamond with chains in crochet with no stitches in the center of the diamond but I am unsure of the best way to get a 120 degree angle turn with only chains. I am needing what looks like a cookie cutter outline in the shape of a diamond. Is this even possible? If not, is there a stitch that I can use that will give me a clean looking obtuse angle with relatively few stitches? I need this exact shape with the space in the middle and everything.

[image: diamond cookie cutter]

Comment: I'm not familiar with the terminology in crochet, and not sure how much this will help, but I'll assume from the question that each loop is called a chain?  To get an angle of 120, you would need to create a ratio of adding 4 rows of chains in the distance of 7 chains, and then reversing that at the peak. You'd come sort of close (127 degrees) with 1:2 (add a row for every two chains to the peak, then reverse).

Comment: @fixer1234 I appreciate your answer but I am looking for a single stitch that can change the direction of my chain, not multiple stitches. I'm basically needing a cookie cutter outline of a diamond. I will change my question to be more clear.

Comment: Can you add some kind of diagram of what you're hoping to achieve? If it's just an outline, being yarn, you probably won't get much, but a visualization of the totality of the project could help someone steer you in the right direction

Comment: @AllisonC I updated my question with a picture of what I am trying to achieve but with crochet chains.

Comment: Thanks; I don't believe what you're looking for is possible, since yarn is soft and the chain will just take on whatever shape it falls into. What's your goal/why do you need to create this shape? Are you open to other options on how to reach the ends you're looking for?

Comment: So are you looking for just a diamond-shaped border (single row), rather than a "solid" crocheted piece in a diamond shape?

Comment: @fixer1234 I am looking for a diamond shaped border.

Comment: @AllisonC so long as I achieve a diamond border with nothing in the center, I am definitely open to other options!

Comment: If it's just a single row, wouldn't it conform to any shape you put it in?

Comment: @DylonJaynes okay, but why? What's the intended use of this item? That would impact the decision of what to recommend.

Comment: @AllisonC It's actually going to be part of a custom lingerie design I am making. A cupless diamond outline to be more specific.

Comment: @fixer1234 I hadn't actually thought of that but I suppose if I slip stitched into the corners of the diamond and chained out some, the tension may be able to maintain the shape. Thanks for the comment!

Comment: Dylon, I'm going through old questions that never got answered. On this one, people had trouble understanding the requirements, but you sort of suggested in comments that some of the ideas might work. Has the question been overtaken by events or are you still looking for an answer? It seems not really answerable from just the info in the question itself. If you're still looking for an answer, could you do an edit to incorporate relevant clarifications in the comments? (cont'd)

Comment: If you solved it, it would be great if you posted a self-answer with how you did it. If you no longer need an answer, we could just close it to put it to bed. Next time you pop into the site, let me know your thoughts. Thanks.

Comment: Ah yes. I never did end up solving it but thank you for your help anyway.